# Python - Traverse previous week same day

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new to python, I have the following use case:

Please refer the calendar below :

[image]

Today's date is 2018-09-12.
I wanted to perform some calculation for previous day with some other conditions.
I have retrieved yesterday's date and day using the following piece of code :

```
yesterday_date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%Y-%m-%d')
yesterday_day = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%A')
```

Now I want to perform some calculations on the same day of previous week.ie : I want to get the date of the previous week for the same day
( Tuesday ). So basically I want to continuously iterate previous week's date for the same day as my Yesterday date day and perform some calculation.

```
Yesterday Date : 2018-09-11

Yesterday Day : Tuesday
```

So my output should be like :

```
2018-09-04
2018-08-28
2018-08-21
2018-08-14
2018-08-07
```

and so on.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: date -= timedelta(days=7) ? And repeat in a loop.

Comment: What about changing your `timedelta(1)` to some variable value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a while loop and using `timedelta(days=days_to_subtract)`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
yesterday_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)  
some_condition = True
i = 0
while (some_condition):
    # do your process with yesterday_date and maybe change the value of some_condition
    i+=1
    yesterday_date -= timedelta(days=7*i)
```

Comment: 1. You don't need the extra computation outside the loop. 2. That's not how comments look in Python. 3. The loop will iterate forever.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You're totally right. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you wanted the to print the last 5 instances of yesterdays date:

```
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
for i in range(0, 5):
    prev_date = yesterday - timedelta(days=i*7)
    print(datetime.strftime(prev_date, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Or if you wanted a list of datetime objects:

```
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
prev_dates = [yesterday - timedelta(days=i*7) for i in range(0, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to loop and use a temp variable:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
yesterday_date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%Y-%m-%d')
yesterday_day = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%A')
date_temp = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
for i in range(5):
    yesterday_date = datetime.strftime(date_temp - timedelta(7), '%Y-%m-%d')
    yesterday_day = datetime.strftime(date_temp - timedelta(7), '%A')
    date_temp = date_temp - timedelta(7)
    print(yesterday_date, yesterday_day, date_temp)
```

**Output:**

```
2018-09-04 Tuesday 2018-09-04 17:04:43.470056
2018-08-28 Tuesday 2018-08-28 17:04:43.470056
2018-08-21 Tuesday 2018-08-21 17:04:43.470056
2018-08-14 Tuesday 2018-08-14 17:04:43.470056
2018-08-07 Tuesday 2018-08-07 17:04:43.470056
```